# What happens if two or more users are reviewing the same question/answer?

Tags: discussion, support

Pretty much as the tile says, what will happen if two users are reviewing the same item?

Is it possible at all, or when one opens a review item, is the reviewed item not available to anyone else while he/she is reviewing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There shouldn't be any parallel reviews of the same post. From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158418/careless-review-upvotes-are-actively-contributing-to-the-quality-problem-not-co/159514#159514):

> An optimization to the Late Answers, First Posts, and Low Quality review queues has been deployed that will keep a single review from being shown to multiple people at the same time. This should help the situation where multiple people would perform reviews which resulted in multiple up-votes. I will continue to monitor these queues closely.

Comment: Thank you, I'm kinda new here and I wasn't aware that it was in the workings.

Comment: @Daniel Beck - Not sure how much rep you need to "review", but there can be instances where more than one person is editing. In that case, you get a notice stating something like " someone else has edited this post while you are editing". It would seem the winner of the edit is the one who make the most substantial changes. I am just noticing that Sekhemty has 510 rep.

Comment: @CarlB Probably because posts can be edited from outside the queue. While not directly related to reviewing, it certainly affects it.